# How to Recovery passphrase bitcoincore

Tags: bitcoin-core

i dont remeber my passphrase of my  bitcoincore wallet.
I try with an hex editor but i don’t know wich string i have to search.
how can i recover it?
Thanks to all can help me.
I’ve followed some post in various forums but I find only instructions for various wallet but nothing for bitcoincore.
I know that is possible to find a pass phrase with an hex editor but I don’t know what searching for

Comment: You cannot. The passphrase is not stored directly in the wallet. It is directly used as an encryption key.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to find the passphrase with a hex editor.
Bitcoin core encrypts your private keys with a random key. This random key is encrypted (AES-256-CBC) with a key derived from your passphrase.

If you remember something from the key (parts of it, letters, even length) you need a program that permutates what you know. If not you can try brute force starting with 1 character and up. Unfortunately when you chose a good key (length>15 characters) this is a near impossible task.

Comment: Maybe I remember a little of my password. Wich kind of program you talk?

Comment: btcrecover if you know most of the password, it's open source

Comment: anyway, a good starting page is wallet-dat.com